# Symbol lookup error since upgrading to Ruby 2.2.0

Tags: ruby, postgresql, puma

I got this error, since upgrading to 2.2.0, only happened when a http request sent to `puma`:

```
puma 2.10.2 (tcp://0.0.0.0:22555): symbol lookup error: 
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/do_postgres-0.10.14/do_postgres/do_postgres.so: 
  undefined symbol: rb_thread_select
```

What are the cause and how to fix this?

Downgrading to 2.1.5 fixes this problem anyway.

Comment: Looks like they already made it an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/datamapper/do/issues/74). No fix as yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pg` gem prior to version 0.14.1 uses the method `rb_thread_select`. This method was removed in Ruby 2.2. According to [their history file](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/b859963462b23f3f07e05eadef59a678b87d9477/History.rdoc?at=default), version 0.15.0 released in March 2013 does not use it anymore:

```
== v0.15.0 [2013-03-03] Michael Granger <ged@FaerieMUD.org>

[...]

Enhancements:

- Make use of rb_thread_fd_select() on Ruby 1.9 and avoid deprecated
  rb_thread_select().

[...]
```

So you may be using an old `pg` gem. Upgrading this gem to at least 0.15.0 should fix your issue.

Comment: I am using ruby-2.3.1 which I just upgraded to using chruby and ruby-install and get this error

/home/x/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/x/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/x/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/json-1.7.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so: undefined symbol: rb_data_object_alloc

Any tips please?

Comment: I do not know where this error comes from. Try upgrading the json gem. It seems to be a different issue. You should post a new question on StackOverfow.